# User lacks privilege or object not found when I do OneToMany relationship

Tags: jpa, spring-boot

So I have 2 entities: developer and project context

I have a bidirectional OneToMany relationship between them but it seem it doesn't work.

Project context has one or more developers

I think I used the annotations well but in the last 90 min I could not find the issue. Can you help me fix it?

Here are the classes:

**ProjectContext:**

```
@Component
@Entity
public class ProjectContext {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "PROJECT_CONTEXT_ID")
    private int id;

    @ElementCollection
    private Map<String, Integer> productBacklog;

private int numberOfStoryPoints;
private int numberOfExpectedWeeks;

@ElementCollection
@MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Map<Skill, Integer> technologies;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "projectContext", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Developer> developers = new ArrayList<Developer>();

public ProjectContext() {
}

 *getters and setters*
}
```

**Developer**

```
@Component
@Entity
public class Developer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "DEVELOPER_ID")
private int id;

private String nume;
private String prenume;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Skill primarySkill;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Skill secondarySkill;
private int motivationLevel;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Gender gender;
private int velocity;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "PROJECT_CONTEXT_ID")
private ProjectContext projectContext;

public ProjectContext getProjectContext() {
    return projectContext;
}

public void setProjectContext(ProjectContext projectContext) {
    this.projectContext = projectContext;
}

public  Developer(){}



*getters and setters*
}
```

**Where I use the classes:**

```
@Component
 public class DatabaseSeeder implements CommandLineRunner {

@Autowired
private ProjectContextRepository projectContextRepository;

@Override
public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
    ProjectContext projectContext = new ProjectContext();

    Map<Skill, Integer> technologies = new HashMap<>();
    technologies.put(Skill.AI, 10);
    technologies.put(Skill.BACKEND, 30);
    technologies.put(Skill.INTEGRATIONS, 30);
    technologies.put(Skill.FRONTEND, 30);

    Map<String, Integer> productBacklog = new HashMap<>();
    productBacklog.put("Filtrare", 30);
    productBacklog.put("Design", 20);

    projectContext.setNumberOfExpectedWeeks(11);
    projectContext.setNumberOfStoryPoints(422);
    projectContext.setProductBacklog(productBacklog);
    projectContext.setTechnologies(technologies);

    Developer developer = new Developer();
    developer.setGender(Gender.F);
    developer.setMotivationLevel(60);
    developer.setNume("Popescu");
    developer.setPrenume("Ana");
    developer.setPrimarySkill(Skill.BACKEND);
    developer.setSecondarySkill(Skill.AI);
    developer.setVelocity(3);
    developer.setProjectContext(projectContext);

    projectContext.getDevelopers().add(developer);

    projectContextRepository.save(projectContext);
}
}
```

Here is what I receive when I run the program:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:735) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:716) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:703) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at eif.devhacks.DevhacksApplication.main(DevhacksApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [insert into project_context (number_of_expected_weeks, number_of_story_points, project_context_id) values (?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:261) ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244) ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521) ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761) ~[spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730) ~[spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504) ~[spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292) ~[spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at eif.devhacks.beans.DatabaseSeeder.run(DatabaseSeeder.java:51) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:732) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:78) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.buildBatchStatement(AbstractBatchImpl.java:136) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.getBatchStatement(AbstractBatchImpl.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2930) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3449) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:582) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:456) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:465) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2963) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2339) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:147) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:61) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517) ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: PROJECT_CONTEXT_ID in statement [insert into project_context (number_of_expected_weeks, number_of_story_points, project_context_id) values (?, ?, ?)]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:75) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy70.prepareStatement(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 50 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: PROJECT_CONTEXT_ID
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readSimpleColumnName(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readSimpleColumnNames(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDML.compileInsertStatement(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    ... 64 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Does the table corresponding to the `Developer` entity (most probably `DEVELOPER`) have a column named `PROJECT_CONTEXT_ID`? Is it accessible by the user configured in JPA?

Comment: PROJECT_CONTEXT_ID is declared in the ProjectContext class: here:    public class ProjectContext {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "PROJECT_CONTEXT_ID")
    private int id; ... I fixed my problem by the way... I deleted: database .log, .lck, .script, .properties